# Getting unicode symbol Â next to pound sign in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following JS code.

When i run the page the js code works fine and all the events i want to happen happen, however where i am trying to set inner htmls and using the £ sign a Â appears before it? Can anyone see why?

```
function displayBasket(){

  basket = document.getElementById("basket"); 
  string = "";
  var basketStorage = localStorage.getItem("basket"); 
  jsonBasket = JSON.parse(basketStorage); 

    var totalPrice = 0;
    itemTotal = 0;
  for (var property in jsonBasket){ 

    var qPrice = jsonBasket[property ].quantity * jsonBasket[property ].cost;
    var total = jsonBasket[property ].quantity;
    string += "<section id='basketPageSection'>";
    if(jsonBasket.hasOwnProperty(property )){ 
      string += "<p>Item: " + jsonBasket[property ].name + "</p>"; 
      string += "<p>Price:'£'" + jsonBasket[property ].cost + "</p>"; 
      string += "<p>Quantity: " + jsonBasket[property ].quantity + "</p>";

    }

    totalPrice += qPrice;
    itemTotal += total;
    string += "</section>";


  }

  string += "<section class='basketSection'> <h3> Total Cost:'£'" + parseFloat(totalPrice).toFixed(2) + "</h3></section>"

  basket.innerHTML = string; 
  displayQuant();
  document.getElementById("calc").value=totalPrice;
}



function displayQuant(){
  var displayQuant = document.getElementById("basketQuantity")
  displayQuant.innerHTML = itemTotal;
}


window.addEventListener("load", displayBasket);
```

Comment: Try `&pound;` or add this in head section in html `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: And read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). :-)

Comment: Fix your file encoding or your encoding header.